# Send input in form and div to mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, input

I have a input field in form and div:

```
<form method="post">
<div id="message">
<input type="text" name="spind" value="" size="55" maxlength="90">
<button>Senden</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Then I have a javascript script for the submit-button and to show this on my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    var message = $("input").val();
    var old = $("#content").html();

    $("#content").html(old + '<p><span style="font-variant:small-caps"><span     
            style="font-size:1.5em"><b><span style="text-transform:capitalize"><?php
            echo $_SESSION["username"];?></span> : </b></span><span style=
            "font-size:1.6em">' + message + "</span></span></p>");
            $("#content").scrollTop($("#content")[0].scrollHeight); 
            });
});
</script>
```

When I put the input in the div inside form with method="post" the message, which should be displayed disappears. This must be because of the form-container.

So, my question is, how can I put the typed message inside the input into a mysql database, without disappearing (and using the defined "button" as submit)?

Comment: are you trying to take input from an input field and store it in a database?

Comment: Check out AJAX functionality in jQuery. Call a php script to insert your message into a database on Submit.

Comment: i want to put the input from the input field in a mysql database. Do i need an input for "submit"? and is there no way to do this without AJAX?